# Why isn't the TextBox changing visiblity?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am using Roblox Studio, and a problem is that I am changing the visiblity thanks to a remote event fired from the server and listened on the client. Basically, I want the text to be visible for the client if something on the server happens. However, the visibility of the text is not changing.

```
local AlreadyBoughtEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("AlreadyBoughtStand")
local textBox = game.StarterGui.MoneyDisplay.Frame.alreadyowns

local function showText()
    textBox.Visible = true
    wait(3)
    textBox.Visible = false
end

AlreadyBoughtEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(showText)
```

And I know the function is reachable because the print statements I put for debug worked, and I double checked the path for the text and it is also proper. I don't know what the problem is here. (Keep in mind the st

Comment: seems you should be using `PlayerGui` rather than `StarterGui`

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is changing the visibility in the StarterGui, not the PlayerGui. Essentially, it is a server-side change instead of targeting the client's gui object that you want.

```
local ReplicatedStorageService = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PlayerService = game:GetService("Players")
local PlayerGui = PlayerService.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild('PlayerGui')
local alreadyBoughtEvent = ReplicatedStorageService:WaitForChild("AlreadyBoughtStand")

local textBox = PlayerGui:WaitForChild("MoneyDisplay"):FindFirstDescendant("alreadyowns")

local function showText()
    textBox.Visible = true
    wait(3)
    textBox.Visible = false
end

alreadyBoughtEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(showText)
```

It is best to get in the habit of using :GetService or :FindService when interacting with services. Referencing a service through the hierarchy (game.Players) will not work if the service hasn't loaded in yet.